# How can i properly use flyTo() with setInterval() or setTimeout() Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, settimeout, setinterval

I have a little problem combining Leaflet function flyTo() with functions setTimeout() and setInterval().

I am trying to make my interactive map to fly all over my country (Croatia) with exact coordinates and exact zoom. The problem is that I can't get the code to loop the flying routes (Zagreb - Osijek - Split - Rijeka).

Hope somebody can point me in the right direction :) Thank you.

I have tried it with counters in while loop and counters with for loop, but there aren't working as well.

```
<script>
       var intervalZg = setInterval(Zagreb, 5000);
        var intervalOs = setInterval(Osijek, 10000);
        var intervalSt = setInterval(Split, 15000);
        var intervalRi = setInterval(Rijeka, 20000);


        function Osijek(){
            mymap.flyTo([45.554614, 18.696247], 13);        
        }

        function Zagreb(){
            mymap.flyTo([45.806367, 15.982061], 13);            
        }

        function Split(){
            mymap.flyTo([43.511787, 16.440155], 13);
        }

        function Rijeka(){
            mymap.flyTo([45.327369, 14.440395], 13);
        }

        function Pula(){
            mymap.flyTo([44.867527, 13.850097], 13);
        }

        function regijaSjever(){
            mymap.flyTo([45.638587, 17.378766], 8.75);
        }

        function regijaJug(){
            mymap.flyTo()
        }

        function regijaZapad(){
            mymap.flyTo()
        }

    </script>
```

For now, this code does fly, he is going to Zagreb then Osijek then Split then Rijeka and then back to Zagreb where it stops.

Comment: `Zagreb` is being executed *every* 5 seconds, while the other ones are executed every 10, 15 and 20 seconds. So, you probably have some weirdly overlapping calls there and `Zagreb` probably randomly cancelling calls which have been made immediately before.

Comment: Yea, it is like that. I can see that the map doesn't stop at all, sorry for the bad information. What I wanna see that i can get the pattern of flying to be repeated over time. Now its just going like Split - Zagreb - Split - Osijek - Rijeka - Osijek and just randomly flies with that timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently flying to Zagreb every 5 seconds - and to Osijek every 10 seconds etc. So the first time you fly to Osijek - you'll also be calling Zagreb.

Maybe set the next location in each ... so

```
function Zagreb() {
   mymap.flyTo([45.806367, 15.982061], 13); 
   setTimeout(Osijek, 5000);
}

function Osijek() {
    mymap.flyTo([45.554614, 18.696247], 13);        
    setTimeout(Split, 5000);
}

function Split() {
   mymap.flyTo([43.511787, 16.440155], 13); 
   setTimeout(Rijeka, 5000);
}

function Rijeka() {
    mymap.flyTo([45.327369, 14.440395], 13);
    setTimeout(Zagreb, 5000);
}

Zagreb();
```

Comment: Wow, awesome. That wasn't on my mind at all. It works perfectly on first iteration, but then after it has done the last region it just starts to fly everywhere every second. Lets say it becomes like a tasmanian devil. Any ideas how to fix that? With some loop or something?

Comment: As long as it's going Z > O > S > R > Z ... it should be fine. Make sure your loop is ok

Answer (score 1):

An approach using just one `setInterval` invocation would look like:

```
// Set up data - an array with the LatLng and the zoom levels for each call

var flights = [
 { latlng: [45.554614, 18.696247], zoom: 13 },
 { latlng: [45.806367, 15.982061], zoom: 13 },
 { latlng: [43.511787, 16.440155], zoom: 13 },
 { latlng: [45.327369, 14.440395], zoom: 13 },
 { latlng: [44.867527, 13.850097], zoom: 13 },
 { latlng: [45.638587, 17.378766], zoom: 8.75 }
];

var flightNumber = 0;

setInterval(function() {

  // flyTo the n-th flight destination...
  map.flyTo( flights[flightNumber].latlng, flights[flightNumber].zoom );

  // The next iteration should fly to the next flight destionation...
  flightNumber++;

  // ...unless we've passed the last flight destination, in which case go 
  // back to the first one.
  // Remember that JS arrays are zero-indexed, so the first element is zero and
  // the last valid element is the (length - 1)-th, hence ">=" instead of ">".
  if (flightNumber >= flights.length) {
    flightNumber = 0;
  }
}, 5000);
```

There are, of course, variations of this technique using different data structures (e.g. adding a name, not having the zoom level, etc), and using the modulo operator (`%`) instead of checking against the array length (e.g. `i = i % length`).